# How to install Redis on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, redis

I am working with Laravel but i have installed all on my own (php, mysql, composer, nginx) and now i need to install Redis and configure it so i could use it for queue driver in Laravel.

How to install it, because it cannot be installed through `apt-get install redis`

i get this error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install redis
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package redis
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install redis-server`

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package redis-server` ...? Linux ubuntu-xenial 4.4.0-112-generic

Comment: Are you trying to install this on Windows? I mean there is `E:` in your line?

Comment: I had to run `sudo apt-get update` to fix `E: Unable to locate package redis-server`

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I think always is better (and simpler) to install from main repos as first option if you don't have any special requirements.

The package you are searching for is named `redis-server`. You can check its package info with `apt show redis-server`.

Also you can search all packages mentioning *redis* with `apt search redis`, or even do some simple filtering using `grep`, use `apt search redis | grep php` to search for `php-redis` or related package(s) for example.

> So, you can simply run:
>
> `sudo apt install redis-server`
>
> on your terminal, to install a fully working `redis`*(server)* environment.

If you have any special requirements, you always can build from source and install as @George posted in his answer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: are there 2 versions of redis? a normal redis and a server redis or what, now i'm confused a bit

Comment: No, there is only one version of the app named _redis_, which has been packaged for ubuntu under the package name `redis-server`.

Comment: OK i have tested it out and i came to a conclusion that i don't need to do anything except `sudo apt-get install redis-server` i don't know what that all is about in the answer above...somehow it is not necessary to do all of that!?

Comment: Yes, the other commands I posted, are there to show how to search for _(all)_ available packages and/or filter them_(in this case related to _redis_ and _php_ inspired by your question)_.

Comment: No I mean the answer from George. He wrote too much. Why? Supervised, Unit file, redis user ... that is all unnecessary i think.

Comment: I think its related to personal preferences, some people prefers building from source _(and doing it for each software version)_ to keep more up to date, etc. I disagree with this except for very special cases, like I mentioned (with a stable system in mind), I prefer Ubuntu team packages because they are pretty well tested against all Ubuntu systems _(desktop, server, core, cloud)_.

Comment: OK...for my needs apt-get install redis-server is more than enough

Comment: I think it's better than enough :)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 64):

To install redis follow these steps:

1. Set up a non-root user with `sudo` privileges
2. Install build and test dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt full-upgrade
   sudo apt install build-essential tcl
   ```
3. Set up redis:

   1. Download latest copy via this [link](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz) or with this

      ```
      curl -O http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
      ```
   2. Create a temporary folder for it in say your `/home/username/redis-stable` directory
   3. Move into created folder and extract it

      ```
      tar xzvf redis-stable.tar.gz
      ```
   4. Change into the folder `cd redis-stable` and build it with

      ```
      make
      make test
      sudo make install
      ```
4. Configure redis:

   1. Create configuration directory:

      ```
      sudo mkdir /etc/redis
      ```
   2. Move sample redis configuration file:

      ```
      sudo cp /home/george/redis-stable/redis.conf /etc/redis
      ```
   3. Edit the file:

      ```
      sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf # or with any other text editor
      ```
   4. Make two changes there:
        `supervised no` to `supervised systemd`
        `dir` to `dir /var/lib/redis` # for persistent data dump
5. Set up the systemd unit file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/redis.service
   ```

   Add the text:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   User=redis
   Group=redis
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
   ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
   Restart=always

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
6. Set up redis user, groups and directories:

   create redis user and group with same ID but no home directory:

   ```
   sudo adduser --system --group --no-create-home redis   
   sudo mkdir /var/lib/redis   # create directory
   sudo chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis   # make redis own /var/lib/redis
   sudo chmod 770 /var/lib/redis   # adjust permission
   ```
7. Test redis:

   1. Start redis service:

      ```
      sudo systemctl start redis
      ```
   2. Check status:

      ```
      systemctl status redis
      ```

      Result of status if started successfully:

      ```
      Output
      ● redis.service - Redis Server
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/redis.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-05-11 14:38:08 EDT; 1min 43s ago
       Process: 3115 ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
       Main PID: 3124 (redis-server)
       Tasks: 3 (limit: 512)
       Memory: 864.0K
       CPU: 179ms
       CGroup: /system.slice/redis.service
                └─3124 /usr/local/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
      ```
   3. Test instance:

      1. Connect:

         ```
         redis-cli
         ```
      2. Test connectivity at prompt:

         ```
         127.0.0.1:6379> ping   # result PONG
         ```
      3. Check ability to set keys:

         ```
         127.0.0.1:6379 set test "It's working!"  # result ok
         ```
      4. Get the key just set:

         ```
         127.0.0.1:6379 get test  # result "It's working!"
         ```
      5. Exit redis:

         ```
         127.0.0.1:6379 exit
         ```
      6. Restart redis and then re-run steps 1, 4, and 5 to connect with the client again and confirm that your test value is still available, hence it's working as expected:

         ```
         sudo systemctl restart redis
         ```
8. Enable redis to start at boot:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable redis
   ```

Source:

[Digital Ocean - how to install and configure redis on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04)

[Direct download links](https://redis.io/download)

Comment: is it needed to do all of this as you have wrote? because i just tried to install redis on a different machine with `sudo apt-get install redis-server` and i can run `redis-cli` and set variables and call them without problem...so i am asking because i want to learn!

Comment: If you want to install the latest version this is the route to take but if your are not so concerned about getting the latest then `sudo apt-get install redis-server` is the path to tow.  Again this is an opportunity to learn how `redis` actually works and how it is setup. I personally prefer to do it this way so I know _in and outs_ of the system and can alter it to suit my needs and expectations.

Comment: I am your fan now.

Comment: @TiagoBertolo obrigado!

Comment: This is different issue but I want to ask that: Is ubuntu 16 similar with centos 7? There is "systemctl" command both of them.

Comment: @kodmanyagha yes they both use `systemctl`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, awesome answer. Thanks for taking the time to put it together. Why do you want us to do step 7:3:6? "re-run steps 1, 4, and 5" if everything went smoothly? If I understand you correctly, you want us to setup non root user, configure Redis, & setup a systemd file again. Do we need to do this for every user? Thanks again and in advance for your response~!

Comment: @PrimeTimeTran please see my update!

Comment: @PrimeTimeTran I think he means re-run steps 1, 4 and 5 of step 7:3, not of the overall procedure.

Comment: Also, you can enable and start the service in one shot: `sudo systemctl enable --now redis`.

Answer (score 35):

First add PPA repository to your OS then update your repository list and install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:redislabs/redis
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redis
```

Comment: using ppa is far more convenient

Comment: This worked great to upgrade in place from the default 3.0 version available in the standard repo to version 4.0 in Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks

Comment: Best answer!!!!

Comment: Still valid for Ubuntu 18.04; I was able to get the latest Redis version this way, as opposed to a much older (1 major release/12 months behind) version.

Comment: The chris-lea PPA seems to be out of date now. [Redis Labs runs a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~redislabs/+archive/ubuntu/redis) that has the most recent releases.

Comment: thanks @abe-voelker I've updated my answer.

Comment: According with https://redis.io/download#from-the-official-ubuntu-ppa your 3rd command is different, Redis uses `sudo apt-get install redis` and you use `sudo apt-get install redis-server`, so what could be the main difference between `redis-server` and `redis` or does not matter?

Answer (score 4):

Following [@George's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/868862/527764), after running `make` (step 3, part 4), `cd` into `redis-stable/utils` and run `./install_server.sh`.

This interactive script will help you define a port and other file locations, and after which you can immediately run `redis-cli`.

That same directory also has a handy script for starting and stopping the server.

Comment: `Job for redis-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript redis-server, action "start" failed.
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-03-29 19:19:59 UTC; 37ms ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)`

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all go to redis.io site

2) and you see there check the download page

3) Open the terminal

4) apt-cache policy redis-server

you able to see the version table for your operating system version display

5) sudo apt-get install redis-server

```
Don't getting this way install. Because redis server installing, but redis server install the your Ubuntu operating system version.
```

6) Easiest way
    Go to redis.io site and click on the download link
    Further you will go scroll on the more down you will see the installation

```
almost same way mac
```

7) First of all you are enter the update command. All the going to repo was update.

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

8) `sudo apt-get install build-essential tcl`

9) `mkdir redis`

10) `wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-4.0.0.tar.gz`

11) Now give the tar command

```
   unzip tar file.
   tar xzf redis-4.0.0.tar.gz
```

12) `cd redis-4.0.0`

13) `make` - making on redis binary

if once finish you can see the "make test" command

14) `src/redis-server` - start the redis server

15) `src/redis-cli` - start the redis client

```
set name vadivel
    Ok
    get name
    "vadivel"
```

16) `sudo make install` - whenever give the redis command on enter the any dir