# Installation of specific version of redis server in Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: server

I need to install Redis-3.2.4 or Redis-3.2.6 on my ubuntu 16.04 machine.How I can install a specific version of this redis can anyone help me to get out from this?

thanks
Nijo

Comment: Down the version file and compile it yourself

Comment: hi george, thanks for your sugesion but how? can i have any step by step guide

Comment: Hey, DO has a write-up on this, go check it out: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: i have tried by using this link but it is installing redis 4

Comment: I do NOT agree that this question is marked as a duplicate. It asks how to install a **specific** version of redis, not just how to install Redis on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download redis-3.2.4.tar.gz or redis-3.2.6.tar.gz from the official http://download.redis.io/releases/ webpage.
2. Install Redis from the  redis-3.2.**X**.tar.gz archive that you downloaded by following the instructions from [How To Install and Configure Redis on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04). <sub>[alternative link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868848/how-to-install-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04/868862#868862)</sub>